# Lambda expressions with Java and Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

The part with .filter() of this code,

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, ?> vals = sc
            .parallelize(Arrays.asList(10, 15, 0))
            .zipWithIndex();
JavaPairRDD<Integer, ?> valsGreaterThan5 = vals
            .filter((k, v) -> v > 5)
            .map((k, v) -> k);
```

gives me a

> Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method call(Tuple2)

error. I don't understand it. I don't even use Tuple2 in my types. What's the cause of the error and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`map` or `filter` get only one argument of type `Tuple2`. It cannot be restructured this way. You can:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, ?> valsGreaterThan5 = vals
        .filter(kv -> v._2 > 5)
        .map(kv -> k._1);
```

or better:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, ?> valsGreaterThan5 = vals
        .filter(kv -> v._2 > 5)
        .keys();
```